# How exactly would one implement auto update on assignment

Tags: c++, automation

Consider the following code:

```
struct data
{
    int foo;
    int bar;
};

data a;
a.foo = 200;
a.bar = 300;

static void update(data* a, int rspec)
{
  if (!rspec) //my data management
  {
      3rdPartyApi->CreateStream();
      3rdPartyApi->PushData(a->foo);
      3rdPartyApi->PushData(a->bar);
      3rdPartyApi->CloseStream();
  }
  else // internal data management
  {
      3rdPartyApi->CreateStream();
      3rdPartyApi->PushData(3rdPartyApi->BufferQueue);
      3rdPartyApi->CloseStream();
  }
  3rdPartyApi->PushStream(3rdPartyApi->GetLastStreamBuffer().POD());
}
```

Lets say I change the value of a.foo or a.bar, and it requires me to call Update there-after the assignment.  Can this be done, without actually calling Update() on each change manually?

[EDIT]
Note that the update function created is also assigned to a function pointer for
the third party API, so it can do it's own internal updating.  So making the update function non-global is impossible, and thus is why the current update function is global.
[EDIT]
I also rewrote my example to be more understanding and correct to the actual API I'm using

e.g

```
3rdPartyApi->StreamUpdate((void (*)(void*, int))update);
```

Comment: Is this your code?  Are you allowed to modify the `data` struct or the `update` function?

Comment: does it matter if you get one Update for the change of `foo` and one for the change of `bar` or do you want to bundle the change ? Also, what should be done if the call to `3rdPartyApi` fails ? Backout the changes ?

Comment: Updates can be in any order, for one change, two changes, the underlying api will automatically manage the bundles since everything is a linear stream in the end.

Comment: Just FWIW, being assigned to a pointer to a function doesn't prevent `update` from being a member function -- it could still be a static member function. I'm not sure that would be an improvement, but it's certainly possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. Use class methods for this. Pass a static method from your class to the 3rd party API as an update function.

```
class data
{
public:
    void set_foo(int new_foo);
    void set_bar(int new_bar);

    int get_foo() const;
    int get_bar() const;

    // This is the update signature which the 3rd party API can accept.
    static void update(void* ptr, int rspec);

private:
    // These are private so we can control their access.
    int foo;
    int bar;
};

void data::set_foo(int new_foo)
{
    foo = new_foo;
    // 'this' is a special pointer for current data object.
    update(this);
}

void data::set_bar(int new_bar)
{
    bar = new_bar;
    update(this);
}

int data::get_foo() const
{
    return foo;
}

int data::get_bar() const
{
    return bar;
}

// This is needed if the 3rd party API can only call C bindings.
// If it's a C++ API this is not needed.
extern "C" {

void data::update(void* ptr, int rspec)
{
    if (!rspec) //my data management
    {
        // You have to cast to data* from void*.
        data* data_ptr = reinterpret_cast<data*>(ptr);

        3rdPartyApi->CreateStream();
        3rdPartyApi->PushData(data_ptr->foo);
        3rdPartyApi->PushData(data_ptr->bar);
        3rdPartyApi->CloseStream();
    }
    else // internal data management
    {
        3rdPartyApi->CreateStream();
        3rdPartyApi->PushData(3rdPartyApi->BufferQueue);
        3rdPartyApi->CloseStream();
    }
    3rdPartyApi->PushStream(3rdPartyApi->GetLastStreamBuffer().POD());
}

} /* extern "C" */
```

Then:

```
3rdPartyApi->StreamUpdate(&data::update);
data a;
a.set_foo(200);
a.set_bar(300);
```

Note that use of a `struct` instead of a `class` is equally fine here. But the convention is to use classes in C++. There is only a minor difference which you can learn later.

Comment: I would put `update` as a `private` method, it does not seem necessary to expose it. You might also consider a "combined" setter (updating both `foo` and `bar`), to reduce the number of calls.

Comment: @Matthieu: Perfect. Added update to private. You are also right about the setter. However, I will leave it as is since this is introductory material.

Comment: Getters and setters are just a bad idea here (and pretty much everywhere). In some languages (e.g., Java) you have little choice, but in C++ there's simply no excuse for subjecting your users to such ugliness. What we have here is data access, which should darned well look and feel to the user like data access.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: In my opinion, getter setters are a little *better* than exposing internal data entirely. It's never wrong to learn one step at a time.

Comment: @junjanes: sorry, but no. Getters and setters are not better than much of anything. What they're doing is forcing the user to deal with your implementation details. Learning one step in the wrong direction is always wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to write code for foo, bar, and data, so let's make it more concrete:

```
class point
{
public:
    int x_coord() const;
    int y_coord() const;

    void move_to(int new_x, int new_y);

private:
    void update_3rd_party();

    int   x;
    int   y;
};

void point::move_to(int new_x, int new_y)
{
    x = new_x;
    y = new_y;
    // whatever else needs to be done

    update_3rd_party();
}
```

Comment: +1 for the attempt at showing that you should not offer *data*, but *operations* in classes, and that doing so will simplify code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make use of [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) design pattern or a slight variant of it.
See this example [here](http://login2win.blogspot.com/2008/05/c-observer-patterm.html).

Comment: right... but do remember that answers consisting exclusively of links are frowned upon :/

Comment: @Matthieu M.: I do know, but I just did'nt want to take the credit for an code example by copy pasting it. In this case I thought the code example in link would give the OP the clue.

Comment: it does, the policy has more to do with "link rot". If your link goes dead, then the answer becomes meaningless.

Comment: @Matthieu M.: Yeah, true, If I do, usually I link to some sources like wikipedia which won't vanish as such, I slipped on this one. My bad...

Answer (score 1):

The usual way would be to turn `foo` and `bar` into some type that overloads the assignment operator:

```
class updated_int { 
    int value;
public:
    updated_int(int init = 0) : value(init) {}

    updated_int &operator=(int new_val) { 
        value = new_val;
        update();
        return *this;
    }

    // You might want to declare this private and not implement it.
    updated_int &operator=(updated_int const &r) { 
        value = r.value;
        update();
        return *this;
    }
    operator int() { return value; }
};

struct data { 
    updated_int foo;
    updated_int bar;
}

data a;
a.foo = 1; // operator= will call update() automatically.
```

Comment: Even though possible, I would rather recommend the use of setters, overloading operators is fine, but it seems rather artificial here.

Comment: @Matthieu: IMO, the use of 'setters' is not only artificial, but downright ugly. I've yet to see a single situation in which I think they should be encouraged.

Comment: I agree with Matthieu. The implementation would actually be more complicate than that because it's the containing structure that is to be passed to update()

Comment: @Maurice: Yes, I'm accustomed to people having been mis-educated so badly that the majority disagree about this. Doesn't change a thing.

Comment: @Jerry: I guess it depends on the situation, I find that setters make it easier to have "extra" logic, like (for example) validation that depend on other fields, the update in this case, etc... The only other solution (with direct access) is having each field register a back reference to the structure they belong to. Not only does it seriously complicate things, but it also means that to store a 32 bits `int`, you now store 128 bits of data (64 bits for the reference pointer, 32 bits for the `int` and 32 bits of padding). *Downright Ugly*.

Comment: @Matthieu: Yes, they simplify this code, but at the expense of exposing its implementation details, and making all the code that uses it butt-ugly. Yes, if you know/find that you're going to create 10 zillion instances of this, you might (grudgingly) give up nicer client code to save memory. But without *knowing* that, you're engaged in premature optimization at best -- and mostly just getting your priorities dead wrong, destroying readability and maintainability to save a few bytes that you have no evidence matter at all.

Comment: At least IMO, it's also worth noting that there's a very good chance that the existing code has a single `update` for both `foo` and `bar` for convenience, not because updating `foo` really needs to write `bar` to the stream (or vice versa). The OP hasn't said for sure, but there's really a pretty fair chance that the back reference, etc., are completely unnecessary in any case.

Comment: @Jerry: actually, I've always found maintainability eased by simplicity and data encapsulation. Directly exposing internals satisfy "simplicity" but fail at providing "encapsulation". Setters provide "encapsulation" and simplify the OP code, at the cost of slightly more verbose client code. IMHO your solution is over-engineered. It has a definite elegance to it (especially in the client code), but I am afraid that the underlying implementation would baffle a future maintainer.

Comment: What I am missing from the discussion, Jerry, is how does the getter/setter approach yield any more of the implementation details. Note that you are basically doing the same with the difference that your setter is called `operator=` and the getter is `operator int`, that together with the fact that you will have to inject a pointer to the containing object for each member to be able to call `update`  on the parent... I don't like the getter/setter approach, but in this particular case it is not worse than the alternatives, and maybe even better.

Comment: @Matthieu: It doesn't directly expose internals at all. Do you honestly believe that spelling a function name as `operator=` or `set_foo` somehow changes the encapsulation provided? If so how?  The client code isn't just slightly more verbose either -- it's a lot more verbose and downright ugly to boot. IMO, a "maintainer" who's baffled by this is simply incompetent.

Comment: @dribeas: it exposes the fact that what was a simple assignment to some data is actually being implemented as a call to a function. It exposes it in a way that the client code *can't* ignore it's being a function instead of an assignment either.

Comment: @Jerry: You're right, your example is encapsulated as well, sorry for the Monday brain fart :/ I still find it over-engineered... as for incompetence, it seems to me that the OP is a beginner, so of course incompetent. He'll learn in time!

Comment: @Matthieu: I'm not at all sure he's at all incompetent. In any case, I'd consider it a bit insulting to just blindly assume he was.